# Create object with data from cURL

Tags: php, json, object, curl

So i'm using cURL with PHP to retrieve some data from a JSON file. The cURL script returns something like this: https://s4.postimg.org/43svl8rot/image.png

I'm using this PHP script:

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://test.pt/api/objgroupinfo/16Jcr05g37KpLklz");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Apikey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);






// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://test.pt/api/dataout/IAfhAfTIUZrCje5q.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Apikey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$headers[] = "X-Startdate: 2016-10-01 00:00:00";
$headers[] = "X-Enddate: 2016-10-10 15:00:00";
$headers[] = "X-Channelnum: 0";
$headers[] = "X-Reclimit: 200";
$headers[] = "User-Agent: test/1.0";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}


$json = json_decode($result,true);
print_R($json);


curl_close ($ch);
```

Can someone help me on how to turn this data into an object or array that i can use? I need to acess this data to show it graphically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode` will convert a JSON encoded string to a PHP variable, see [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). It looks like your code is already doing this.

Comment: But how can i use this data now and save it to variables?